# DxDesigner Design Rule Check Errors

Tags: design-rules, dxdesigner

I'm using Mentor Graphics's DxDesigner to design a PCB. As a side note, I do know what design rule checks (DRCs) are, but I'm completely new to DxDesigner and am not sure what each of their DRCs are.

I currently have 335 errors.

- 328 connectivity errors

  - drc-106 --> more than one driver on a net
  - drc-121 --> redundant hierarchical symbol on net
- 7 migration errors

  - drc-001 --> Property ______ has invalid format
  - Note: the specified properties contain these characters: letters, numbers, dashes

If anyone knows how to fix these DRCs that would be great. Otherwise, a link to some good documentation would also be great.

Comment: DxD is a total piece of crap when I insisted our company stopped using it back in 2010. I'm sorry to see folk still using it.

Answer (score 1):

As a first port of call I would try loading the help documentation in DxDesigner.? There is actually a surprising amount of information which has helpful search functionality.

In any case, hopefully the following will help:

- DRC-106 is basically you have more than one pin of type "output" connected to a net (e.g. two logic gate outputs) which is usually indicative of either a bad connection, or incorrect pin type in one or other of the symbols.
- DRC-121 indicates that you have a hierarchy symbol (e.g. "hier-in" or "hier-out", etc.) symbol attached to a net in your schematic, but you are not using it for anything. As such that symbol is redundant.

Not sure about DRC-001.

Comment: How do I get rid of the "more than one driver" error if all I'm doing is connecting pin1 to pin1 of two different ICs?